# Python Behave hooks not being called

Tags: python-behave

I'm trying to use some of the hooks provided in behave API ( https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=after_all#environment-file-functions ), but the function defined inside the environment.py file are never called. I've tried to move the file to several different folders ( features, steps ... ) but none of them seems to work.
Where is the project structure:
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Please provide more details - what command you're using to run behave, are your feature files executed, what errors are you getting (if any), etc. The file structure looks fine and the environment.py is placed ok, so we need more clues

Comment: I'm just running behave, with no extra arguments. I dont get any errors, but nothing happens on the fixtures files...

Answer (score 0):

All look good, just change `ctx` to `context` in your hook.
It should look like in documentation: `before_step(context, step)`. Keep the context.